# Unit testing test for Ok Result

Tags: c#, unit-testing, httpresponse

I have the following (simplified) controller:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Profile(UpdateProfileModelAllowNulls modelNullable)
{         
    ServiceResult<ProfileModelDto> result = await _profileService.UpdateProfile(1);

    return Ok(result);         
}
```

And:

```
public async Task<ServiceResult<ProfileModelDto>> UpdateProfile(ApplicationUserDto user, UpdateProfileModel profile)
{
     //Do something...
}
```

and the following NUnit test:

```
[Test]
        public async Task Post_Profile()
        {
            var result = _controller.Profile(new UpdateProfileModelAllowNulls() { Email = "testEmail@tt.co.uk", DisplayName = "TestDisplay"}) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Task<<ProfileModelDto>>;
            Assert.IsNotNull(result);            
        }
```

In my NUnit test, I am trying to check for an Ok result using this tutorial https://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/testing-and-debugging/unit-testing-with-aspnet-web-api.

My problem is that I cannot convert to an `OkNegotiatedContentResult`, i assume because I am not passing in the correct object, but I cannot see what object I should be passing in. As far as I can see, I am passing in the correct object eg: `OkNegotiatedContentResult<Task<<ProfileModelDto>>;`

but this does not work.

I have also tried:

```
var result = _controller.Profile(new UpdateProfileModelAllowNulls() { Email = "testEmail@tt.co.uk", DisplayName = "TestDisplay"}) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<Task<IHttpActionResult>>;
```

But this does not work either.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: as OkNegotiatedContentResult<ProfileModelDto> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You controller is Async so you should call it like:

```
var result = (_controller.Profile(new UpdateProfileModelAllowNulls() { Email = "testEmail@tt.co.uk", DisplayName = "TestDisplay"}).GetAwaiter().GetResult()) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<ProfileModelDto>;
```

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @esiprogrammer, the method is async, so I needed to add the awaiter.

I was able to fix it by doing the following:

```
    var result = _controller.Profile(new UpdateProfileModelAllowNulls() { Email = "testEmail@wwasoc.co.uk", DisplayName = "TestDisplay"});
    var okResult = await result as OkNegotiatedContentResult<ServiceResult<ProfileModelDto>>;
```

I have accepted @esiprogrammer answer as he answered the question correctly, and also before me